# Paging in an edited Webpart

Tags: 2007, web-part

I have a webpart that I have edited to pull all tasks that are not completed. I got it from Christophe, his task rollup. (http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/sharepoint-user-toolkit/Pages/Tasks-Lists-Rollup.aspx)

I want to enable paging on it. What is the code that I need to add to this webpart to accomplish this?

Comment: You'll need to roll your own XSL or contact Christophe to see if he can alter the generator to include paging.

Comment: Any useful links on rolling my own XSL?

Comment: Creating a data view web part in Sharepoint Designer will give you an idea on what the paging looks like.  It's pretty involved.

Answer (score 1):

Christophe's script does not provide paging support, it will only retrieve up to 500 items.  To enable paging, you'll need to create your own paging markup.  Creating a dataview web part in Sharepoint Designer will give you context on what the markup looks like for paging.